# JavaScript string generator not working

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so don't judge me please :)

I have a real basic string generator, but it isn't working the way I want it to, it prints a 1 letter string (e.g "c") rather than a multi-letter string

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for (var i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) {
    var news = "";
    news = news + alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)]
    if (i == alphabet.length - 1) {
        console.log(news)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly when posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize the variable `news` outside the `for` loop. Declaring is not a problem when we use `var` to do that, because it will be hoisted to the top. But initialization is important. That has to be outside the for loop.

```
var alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var news="";

for (var i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) {
  news=news+alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*alphabet.length)]
  if (i==alphabet.length-1) {
    console.log(news)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor mistake. Just define `var news = '';` outside for loop. (Also, use semicolons).

```
var alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var news="";
for (var i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) {
    news=news+alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*alphabet.length)]
  if (i==alphabet.length-1) {
    console.log(news)
  }
}
```